# flex 3 cancel tooltip event

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I am trying to cancel a tooltip event (I only want it to display when the mouse is hovered over a certain area), and can't seem to figure it out. I tried stopPropagation, preventDefault, and stopImmediatePropagation, but none of them seem to work.

Here the code I am using:

```
        private function toolTipCreateHandler(event:ToolTipEvent):void {
            if(event.currentTarget.mouseX < 130) {
                var tooltip:PhotoToolTip = new PhotoToolTip();
                tooltip.src = event.currentTarget.toolTip;
                event.toolTip = tooltip;
            }
            else {
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step one, add an event listener to detect when the mouse leaves the area you want the tooltip, run a function and title it something like "toolTipDestroyer"

Step two, You need to call the destroy method of the tooltip manager

```
private function toolTipDestroyer():void {
    if (myToolTip) {
        ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(myToolTip);
        myToolTip= null;
    }
}
```

Also, just for readability, give your tooltip some other name than "tooltip", you'll find it easier to follow up on your code later. My example names it "myToolTip"

Comment: For my case, I think it would make the most sense to just call destroyToolTip toolTipCreateHandler function, as I don't want it display at all if it is not within the region specified. 

The issue here is that events on tied to a textArea, and as a result, the mouseOut won't suffice.

Comment: If that works go for it. I admit that I didn't test it, it just seemed to me like it wouldn't work in Flex since there isn't an OnHover event.

Comment: turns out that didn't work. The problem is if that the user hasn't hovered over the correct area yet, the tooltip instance is null.